# Converting long table to wide and creating columns according to the rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
Customer_ID     Category   Products 
  1               Veg         A
  2               Veg         B
  3              Fruit        A   
  3              Fruit        B
  3               Veg         B 
  1              Fruit        A
  3               Veg         C 
  1              Fruit        C
```

I want to find out the for each customer ID for each category which products were bought, and create a column for each product accordingly. The output would look like this:

```
Customer_ID     Category    Pro_1    Pro_2     Pro_3
  1               Veg        A        NA         NA
  1              Fruit       A        NA         C
  2               Veg        NA       B          NA
  3               Veg        NA       B          C
  3              Fruit       A        B          NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), but if duplicates rows data are concanecate together:

```
df = df.groupby(['Customer_ID','Category','Products'])['Products'].sum().unstack()
df.columns = ['Pro_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df.columns)+1)]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   Customer_ID Category Pro_1 Pro_2 Pro_3
0            1    Fruit     A  None     C
1            1      Veg     A  None  None
2            2      Veg  None     B  None
3            3    Fruit     A     B  None
4            3      Veg  None     B     C
```

Another solution with helper column, triples has to be unique:

```
#if not unique triples remove duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Customer_ID','Category','Products'])

df['a'] = df['Products']
df = df.set_index(['Customer_ID','Category','Products'])['a'].unstack()
df.columns = ['Pro_{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df.columns)+1)]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   Customer_ID Category Pro_1 Pro_2 Pro_3
0            1    Fruit     A  None     C
1            1      Veg     A  None  None
2            2      Veg  None     B  None
3            3    Fruit     A     B  None
4            3      Veg  None     B     C
```

Comment: The problem here is when we unstack we end up with as many products as the number of unique values of the products.  This results to new columns that are are not tight to the customer ID and Category. I am trying to create columns based on the products on the group level

Comment: Is possible change input data by it?

Comment: what do you mean by changing input data?

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) :

```
pd.crosstab([df['Customer_ID'],df['Category']], df['Products'])
```

output:

```
Products              A  B  C
Customer_ID Category         
1           Fruit     1  0  1
            Veg       1  0  0
2           Veg       0  1  0
3           Fruit     1  1  0
            Veg       0  1  1
```

Afterwards you can reset the index for a similar solution to what you wanted.

```
df = df.reset_index()
Products  Customer_ID Category  A  B  C
0                   1    Fruit  1  0  1
1                   1      Veg  1  0  0
2                   2      Veg  0  1  0
3                   3    Fruit  1  1  0
4                   3      Veg  0  1  1
```

Comment: The crosstabing happens on all products, how can we just target the products on the Customer ID and Category level?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (don't mind the IO thing it is just for simple copy/paste)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Customer_ID     Category   Products 
  1               Veg         A
  2               Veg         B
  3              Fruit        A   
  3              Fruit        B
  3               Veg         B 
  1              Fruit        A
  3               Veg         C 
  1              Fruit        C"""), sep='\s+')
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['Products']))
g = df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Category']).sum()
print(g)
```

output:

```
                      A  B  C
Customer_ID Category         
1           Fruit     1  0  1
            Veg       1  0  0
2           Veg       0  1  0
3           Fruit     1  1  0
            Veg       0  1  1
```